# mdframed: splittopskip does not work when the first object after splitting is another mdframed box

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, mdframed

### Question

I would like to add space in an `mdframed` environment after a splitting (a page break) and in the case where the first object after the splitting (the page break) is another `mdframed` environment. Is it possible?

### Picture and code

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = red, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 11cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = blue, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 9cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.
\end{mdframed}

\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe my revisions are complete.  There is a version that inserts padding in all nested frames, using `splittopskip` of the outer frame for the height.  Unfortunately, I had to give it its own name, `Mdframed`, instead of revising `mdframed`.  Good news is that my MWE allows either manual- or auto-padding (throughout the document), based on a parameter setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This provides both a semi-automatic and a fully automatic solution to the problem... In all cases, it is "automatic" in that all the `mdframe` parameters necessary to create the color padding are taken directly from the environments without user intervention.  If the user opts for the "semi-automatic" solution form, it allows them to manually invoke a macro `\padframe[padheight]` to include the padding when and where he wants.

In the fully automatic solution, an environment `Mdframed` will stick the padding in for every nested frame, whether it is split or not (but not the outer frame).  In both semi-automatic and fully automatic versions, the default pad height is the `splittopskip` of the outer frame.

The parameters it automatically grabs from the outer `mdframe` environment are `backgroundcolor`, `userdefinedwidth`, `innerleftmargin`, `innerrightmargin`, and `splittopskip` (the default padheight); and from the inner `mdframe` environment, it grabs `innertopmargin`, `userdefinedwidth`, `innerleftmargin`, and `innerrightmargin`.

It uses those parameters to build a set of `\rule`s that will give the appearance of "padding" in the color of the outer `mdframe`.

REVISION notes:

V1: Initial answer

V2: With the use of length `\padvslop`, eliminated horizontal ghost line when nesting/padding an `mdframe` in the *middle* of page.  Once vslop was added, I had to revise the manner of building my top rule `\laps`.  Also, made `splittopskip` of the outer frame the default pad height, rather than `splitbottomskip` of the outer frame.

V3: Accounted for asymmetric left/right margins of outer `mdframe` when building pad laps.

V4: Made calls to `\padframe` from the outer `mdframe` inconsequential (they are ignored).  This means all that is left to do is to try to make it so that `mdframed` always invokes `\padframe` upon entry.  So far my efforts have not met with success.

V5: Introduced `Mdframed` to automatically insert padding.  I made my MWE to either set to "manually insert padding" or "automatically insert padding", through the setting of a parameter `\mdfManualPaddding` as either `{T}` or `{F}`.  When using automatic padding, manual invocations of `\padframe` are ignored.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% DECIDE WHETHER YOU WANT TO MANUALLY INSERT PADDING AND SET ACCORDINGLY
\def\mdfManualPadding{F}% {T} or {F}
%%%%%
\newlength\padvslop% TO ELIMINATE HORIZONTAL GHOST LINES
\padvslop=0.3pt% KEEP AS SMALL AS POSSIBILE,
% SINCE THIS WILL BE A TOP MARGIN OVERRUN ON PADDED SPLIT FRAMES
\makeatletter
\let\svmdframed\mdframed
\let\svendmdframed\endmdframed
\def\mdfl@splittopskip{U}% SERVES AS INITIALIZATION
\def\mdf@backgroundcolor{white}% SERVES AS INITIALIZATION
\def\mdfl@userdefinedwidth{U}% SERVES AS INITIALIZATION
\def\mdfl@innerleftmargin{U}% SERVES AS INITIALIZATION
\def\mdfl@innerrightmargin{U}% SERVES AS INITIALIZATION
\def\outermdparams{\edef\oSTS{\mdfl@splittopskip}\edef\oBGC{\mdf@backgroundcolor}%
  \edef\oILM{\mdfl@innerleftmargin}\edef\oIRM{\mdfl@innerrightmargin}%
  \edef\oUDW{\mdfl@userdefinedwidth}}
\newlength\SidebarWidth
\newlength\LRMarginDiscrepancy
\newcounter{mdfnestlevel}
\newcommand\@padframe[1][\oSTS]{%
  \ifnum\themdfnestlevel=1\else{% IF CALLED FROM OUTER FRAME, IGNORE!
  \def\ITM{\mdfl@innertopmargin}%
  \def\ILM{\mdfl@innerleftmargin}%
  \def\IRM{\mdfl@innerrightmargin}%
  \def\UDW{\mdfl@userdefinedwidth}%
  \def\PBS{#1}%
  \SidebarWidth=\dimexpr\oUDW-\UDW%
  \SidebarWidth=.5\SidebarWidth%
  \LRMarginDiscrepancy=\dimexpr\oILM-\oIRM%
  \LRMarginDiscrepancy=.5\LRMarginDiscrepancy%
  \fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0pt%
  \rule[-\PBS]{0pt}{0pt}% 
  \smash{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ITM-\PBS+\padvslop}{\llap{\colorbox{\oBGC}{%
      \rule{\dimexpr\ILM+\SidebarWidth+\LRMarginDiscrepancy+1pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\PBS}}\kern-1pt}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ITM-\PBS+\padvslop}{%
      \colorbox{\oBGC}{\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\PBS}}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ITM-\PBS+\padvslop}{\rlap{\kern-1pt\colorbox{\oBGC}{%
      \rule{\dimexpr\IRM+\SidebarWidth-\LRMarginDiscrepancy+1pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\PBS}}}}%
  }}%
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces\fi%
}
\if T\mdfManualPadding
%%%%% DEFINE THIS TO USE mdframed OR Mdframed WITH MANUAL INVOCATIONS OF \padframe
  \newcommand\padframe[1][\oSTS]{\@padframe[#1]}
  \renewcommand\mdframed{\stepcounter{mdfnestlevel}\outermdparams\svmdframed}
  \renewcommand\endmdframed{\svendmdframed\addtocounter{mdfnestlevel}{-1}}
  \newenvironment{Mdframed}[1][]{%
     \begin{mdframed}[#1]%
    }{%
     \end{mdframed}%
    }
\else
%%%%% OR ELSE DEFINE THIS TO USE NEWLY CREATED Mdframed,
%%%%% WHICH AUTO-INSERTS PADDING WITH NESTED FRAMES 
  \newcommand\padframe[1][]{\relax}% IGNORE MANUALLY INSERTED PADS
  \newenvironment{Mdframed}[1][]{%
     \stepcounter{mdfnestlevel}%
     \outermdparams%
     \begin{mdframed}[#1]%
     \@padframe\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax%
    }{%
     \end{mdframed}%
     \addtocounter{mdfnestlevel}{-1}%
    }
%%%%%%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\mytext{%
Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus 
nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat 
molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo 
ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit 
quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum 
suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.}

\begin{Mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 5mm, 
backgroundcolor = red, 
skipabove = 5mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 11cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 5mm, % splittopskip IS THE DEFAULT TO APPLY AS HEIGHT OF A NESTED \padframe
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 1cm, 
align = center]

\padframe% USE THIS FORM WITH MANUAL PADDING
THIS CASE SHOWS A NESTED mdframe WITH PADDING ON SAME PAGE.  THE MARGINS ARE
ASYMMETRICAL. THE LENGTH padvslop WAS USED TO ELIMINATE HORIZONTAL GHOST LINE
\mytext\par
\mytext

\begin{Mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 5mm, 
backgroundcolor = blue, 
skipabove = 5mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 9cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]

\padframe% USE THIS FORM WITH mdframed, NOT Mdframed
\mytext
\end{Mdframed}
\end{Mdframed}

\clearpage

\begin{Mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = red, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 11cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 5mm, % splittopskip IS THE DEFAULT TO APPLY AS HEIGHT OF A NESTED \padframe
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]

THIS CASE SHOWS A NESTED mdframe WITH PADDING ON THE FOLLOWING PAGE.
\padframe% USE THIS FORM WITH mdframed, NOT Mdframed
\mytext\par
\mytext\par
\mytext\par
\mytext

\begin{Mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = blue, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 9cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]

\padframe[3cm]% USE THIS FORM WITH mdframed, NOT Mdframed
\mytext
\end{Mdframed}
\end{Mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

When the inner `mdframe` is, for example, defined as

```
\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 1.1cm, 
innertopmargin = 1.1cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = blue, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 9cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 1.1cm, 
align = center]

\padframe[1cm] % SPECIFY PAD HEIGHT EXPLICITLY
\mytext
\end{mdframed}
```

in which the padframe height is specified as 1cm, and the `innerleft/rightmargin`s and `innertopmargin` are all set to 1.1cm, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is two time `\def\mytext{%`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Colas  Apparently I had a typo, and you fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: I am waiting to see if someone will come with a fully automatic solution before giving you the bounty. When you use use your command in two nested mdframed environments with no text in the first one, there seems to be a very very thin blue line before the additional red space.

Comment: @Colas  Could you place an addendum on your question with an MWE showing this pathological case?  Then I could have a look.  As far as automation, it may be possible to "automate" my solution (after a fashion) by essentially forcing this added rule-bar to *every* nested `mdframe`, even those which didn't begin on a new page.  Is there any interest in that, or would that be unacceptable in its nature?  And, by all means, wait out the full time for better answers to appear.

Comment: @Colas  Also, I used `splitbottomskip` of the outer frame to set the default frame pad height.  I guess I should instead use `splittopskip`, but my question is, do I use the `splittopskip` specification from the outer or inner frame?

Comment: Yes it could be a good idea. Maybe one could add an option like `intermdframedheight` that would take over `skipabove.2`, `splittopskip.1` when  we are in this case. Can you easily detect that an `mdframe` is nested?

Comment: See my previous answer, you could add a new parameter, IMHO.

Comment: @Colas I think I can detect a nesting frame as follows.  In the preamble, I currently set `\def\mdfl@splitbottomskip{0pt}`, not because it is used, but merely because it must be defined in advance so that `\outermdparams` doesn't blow up on invocation of the outer box.  If I instead set `\def\mdfl@splitbottomskip{U}` (for "undefined"), then this parameter will only have a value of "U" when you are entering the outer `mdframe` and can be tested as such.

Comment: Good idea! Have you seen my edit to my question with the MWE? Thanks for your help!! I have never coded in `LaTeX` but it seems to be the most cryptic language I have ever seen!!!

Comment: I read your code. I could never have done it!!! Did you forget an `l` in `\mdf@backgroundcolor`? When did you capture the `widths`, etc. of the outer frame? What's the use of `edef`? Is the `@` just another letter (because of `\makeatletter`)?

Comment: @Colas : `\mdfl@...` implies a length macro, whereas `\mdf@...` is for non-length macros (I gleaned this by looking at the mdframed.sty file).  The `\outermdparams` macro captures the outer frame data, since it is executed just prior to beginning the inner frame.  I need to use `\edef` to capture that data, because an `\edef\x{}` captures the value of `\x` at the time that the `\edef` is issued, whereas a `\def\x{}` captures the value of `\x` at the time `\x` is issued.  `@` is just a letter after `\makeatletter` and is commonly used in package variables, to avoid conflict with user variables.

Comment: @Colas Here is an example of the def/edef difference:  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\frame{outer}
\edef\ewhichframe{\frame}
\def\whichframe{\frame}
\def\frame{inner}
\noindent This is whichframe: \whichframe\\
This is ewhichframe: \ewhichframe
\end{document}`